# W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine, Sound does not work

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator, text-to-speech

I am now trying to implement a function that when the user clicks the button, it will speak input words inside the EditText. But I could not find how to improve my codes, any helps or advice, please.

Following this youtube video
[Working with TTS in Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sBRZxOvZmM)

As I checked some sites, I tried everything, for instance,

・Change the emulator made 3 emulators

・Setting->System->Languages & input->Advanced->Text-to-speech output

・Re-install English(US)

・Preferred engine is Google Text-to-speech Engine

・Check the SDK version, and it is 30

Finally realized that 「W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine」 appears in the android studio

↓MainActivity.java

```html
package com.example.sounttest2;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

    int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 1000;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tts);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                if(text.length() > 0){
                    textToSpeech.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }
            }
        });

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS){
                textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }}

    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {
        if(i == textToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (i == textToSpeech.ERROR){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_tts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

↓strings.xml

```html
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Test</string>
    <string name="hint">"Please Input Something"</string>
    <string name="button">Text To Speech</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: If your are using sdk version 30 you need to go back on 28 it will work]

If your are using sdk version 30 you need to go back on 28 it will work

Answer (score 1):

The issue was just an SDKVersion, I used 30. but 29 and 28 SDKVersion is the best for implementation.

[See here](https://youtu.be/aNkHwM4Bb84)